# dependency resolution in java and Kotlin mixed project

Tags: java, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am working on the project which has both java and Kotlin files. The module is created in Kotlin. I created a worker class in java that needs a client to make an API call. The client is initialized in Kotlin's APP_MODULE file. Is there any way I can provide the client in my java worker class.

Below is the code of the module.

```
val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .build()

val backendUrl = "https://localhost:9090"
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(backendUrl)
    .client(okHttp)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

single {
    okHttp
}

single {
    retrofit.create(DriverClient::class.java)
}

single {
    TaskManagerService()
}
```

I have a worker class that needs `DriverClient`. Below is the code:

```
public class DataCollectionTaskWorker extends Worker {

private DriverClient driverClient;

public DataCollectionTaskWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem now you faced?

Comment: I don't know how to assign driverClient which is created in App_Module.kt to DataCollectionTaskWorker class.

Comment: call it the way you'd call any other file in Java. Java interops with Kotlin and you usually don't recognize the difference